# How to fit SGDRegressor with two numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to learn `SGDRegressor`. I generate my own data but I don't know how to fit that into the algorithm. I get this error.

```
x = np.random.randint(100, size=1000)
y = x * 0.10
clf = linear_model.SGDRegressor()
clf.fit(x, y, coef_init=0, intercept_init=0)
```

> Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [   1 1000]

I'm new to python and Machine Learning. What do I miss?

Comment: `x` is incorrectly shaped.  try `x = x.reshape(1000,)`

Comment: Can you add that to the answer so I can accept please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> np.random.randint(100, size=1000)
```

will give you a 1 x 1000 array.
Your features and target variables need to be in a column.  Try

```
>>> x = x.reshape(1000,)
```